# Confused about Responsive Frameworks > Bootstrap Like

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, frameworks, zurb-foundation

I want to learn a Responsive framework. I know about Bootstrap, Foundation, Gumby, UI Kit and Semantic UI, but as I read about all of them and I saw a lot of comparisons I got confused and I don't know what to choose, or how to even start. All of them have good helpful docs.

If you use any such framework, even if not mentioned, please explain why you chose it, how you like using it, and describe its pros and cons.

Comment: This type of question isn't a very good fit for SO. Try this: http://www.quora.com/For-those-who-have-implemented-a-responsively-designed-website-using-a-framework-which-framework-did-you-use-and-why-What-criteria-led-you-to-use-that-framework-over-another

Answer (score 1):

I generally use skeleton, and start with HTML5 boilerplate. I like skeleton because it's CSS based, and easy to use. Don't get me wrong, I like Foundation, and some of the others you mentioned, but this has always been my go to.

Answer (score 0):

I myself prefer Bootstrap,  because it has bigger community in contrast to other frameworks and due to that fact it's much easier to find any needed feature. Anyway, You can have a look on "Responsive CSS Framework Comparison" table which provides a list of features, pros, and cons here: 
http://responsive.vermilion.com/compare.php